# Significato di "sotto pegno" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> Nora Almagià maritata Ramundo, come lascia capire il suo cognome di ragazza, era ebrea (anzi, i suoi parenti vivevano tuttora, da parecchie generazioni, nel piccolo ghetto di Padova); però lei non voleva farlo sapere a nessuno, e se n’era confidata solo con lo sposo e con la figlia, **sotto pegno** severissimo di segreto. Nei casi ufficiosi e pratici, usava anche di camuffare il proprio cognome di ragazza, convertendolo da *Almagià* in *Almagía*: persuasa, con tale spostamento d’accento, di fabbricarsi un’impunità! In ogni modo, a quei tempi, invero, le occulte discendenze *razziali* non venivano ancora esplorate, né sindacate.

La mia domanda è sull'espressione "sotto pegno" che appare in questo brano. Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che "pegno" può avere il senso figurato di "prova" o "garanzia" di qualcosa. Tuttavia, non riesco a capirne il significato in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sotto pegno nel contesto da te citato significa a patto, a condizione di mantenere il segreto.

L’accezione di [pegno](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pegno/) adatta a questo caso è la seguente:

> 3. In senso fig., garanzia solenne, prova, testimonianza di un impegno morale, di un sentimento, di un legame anche affettivo: *la concordia è
>    p. di libertà; ti regalo questo libro come p.,* o *in p., di amicizia;
>    ebbero un figlio, dolce p. del loro amore.*

Lo sposo e la ragazza avevano giurato e si erano impegnati a non fare parola con nessuno riguardo alle origini ebree della madre e della di lei famiglia.

Comment: Cioè, sposo e figlia dovevano dare garanzia severissima o prova severissima di mantenere il segreto?

Comment: O forse il senso è che, in cambio di sapere questo su Nora, marito e figlia dovevano perdere qualcosa: il diritto di parlare delle origini della loro sposa-madre. E questo doveva essere rispettato in modo stritto (severissimo).

Comment: E quello che hai scritto nell'ultima frase sarebbe più o meno come la garanzia che davano marito e figlia sul loro impegno, no? E che questa garanzia fosse "severissima" sta a significare che non si poteva assolutamente fare nessuna eccezione?

Comment: Esattamente. Non doveva mai per nessun motivo essere divulgato il segreto. Come dice l’autrice essere ebrei non era ancora pericoloso in quei tempi, con probabile riferimento alle leggi razziali del 1938.

Comment: @Charo Esatto, qui *pegno* è usato più o meno come sinonimo di *impegno*

Comment: @abarisone: Sì, infatti questo accade poco prima della prima guerra mondiale ma, nel futuro, questa famiglia dovrà subire l'avvenimento del fascismo e delle leggi razziali.